# show upload dialog immediately when open a page using javascript

Tags: javascript

This code works on Firefox, but does not work on Mac/iOS Safari.
Is there a way to make it work?

```
$(function(){ 
setTimeout(function(){ $("input[name='upload']").trigger('click'); },1000);
});
```

Comment: For best results I suggest you  add  jQuery and safari tags, and remove the iOS tag.

Answer (score 1):

not sure if this will work, but maybe you can try.

Add this meta tag at the top

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

And for the input field maybe try

```
<input accept="image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg" type="file" name="upload" />
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently that's prohibited. probably in terms of security.
https://mariusschulz.com/blog/programmatically-opening-a-file-dialog-with-javascript